# Character Encoding Issue in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

Character Encoding Issue in IE

Here is a paragraph text which is not properly rendering in IE

Original Text - The evolutionary improbability of ‘generalism’ in nature, with special reference to insects

Shows in IE - The evolutionary improbability of â€˜generalismâ€™ in nature, with special reference to insects

Is there any way in Javascript/jQuery to rectify this issue provided the text is wrapped in a 'p' tag?

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you have not specified page encoding. add this in Head section.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```